# Could it be possible to create an list in the treeview? Odoo

Tags: list, tree, treeview, odoo

Like this
[image]

Please help me, any solution i need

Comment: By grouping you can create list view.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to display a `Onemany` or `Many2many` field directly in a tree view but they will only display the number of records, not the content of those records.

```
(2 records)
```

There is not any way to display each of those records on their own line as you've shown in your question.

You could possibly use a computed `Text` field just to display on tree views, such as below.

Note: You haven't provided any real information related to your situation so I'm going to use an example. Suppose you want to view a list of Sales Orders and, within the list view, you want to display the name of each product on that Sales Order.

```py
Class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    # This is whatever field has the multiple records you want to display 
    order_line = fields.One2many('sale.order.line',
                                 'order_id',
                                 string='Order Lines', ...)

    order_line_text = fields.Text('Order Lines (Text)',
                              compute='_compute_order_line_text',
                              store=True)

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('order_line')
    def _compute_order_line_text(self):
        for order in self:
            product_names = [line.product_id.name for line in order.order_line]
            # You may have to use a different line breaking character
            # It depends what is rendered in the list view
            order.order_line_text = "\n".join(product_names)
```

If this solution does not work how you want, then the next option would be to create a menu that displays a list of the `x2many` fields (`order_line` in this example).

You would basically create a menu and an action to display a list of all Sales Order Lines, then you could group by Sales Order, which would be (at least very similar to) your example in your question.